# delay NgModule declaration with async import module

Tags: angular, asynchronous, import, module, promise

I would like to dynamically import a third-party module and check it. Then declaration in NgModule depends on it exist or not(true/false). Something like my code below. The problem is: the dynamically import is a Promise. I need that NgModule declaration AFTER the import Promise has loaded. How could i solve it?

```
let loaded = false;

import('ngx-color-picker').then((module) => {
    console.log(module);
    loaded = true;
}); // => it takes time

// the Module suddenly declaration => i need to delay it somehow and
// runs AFTER the above import Promise has loaded
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        loaded ? SmNgxColorPickerComponent : [],
    ],
    imports: [
        // --- Angular Base imports ---
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,

        // --- Angular Material imports ---
        MatInputModule,

        // --- Vendor imports ---
        loaded ? ColorPickerModule : [],
    ],
    exports: [
        loaded ? SmNgxColorPickerComponent : [],
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class SmNgxColorPickerModule {

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, why don't you simply lazyload this module with the router so this library will get separated from the main bundle?

Comment: I really need it to check inside NgModule that the third-party library/module is exist or not(not inside app-routing.module or main app) when the app start to run only once(init) and handle it(like a try-catch dynamically)

Comment: I don't think I understand your need, why would you need to check if a third-party library exists?

Comment: I try to explain it but sorry for my bad english: I build my own library to publish in a public ng-modules. This library contains more modules and some modules build on a third-party library. So, if i dont want to use in my main app that module from my own package what built on a third-party library then i dont want to download that third-party package(like peer dependency) in the development node_modules. And my own module should knows it(dynamically).

Comment: I also want this solution. As I want to import recaptcha module in my login module but it creates performance issue as per google insights so I want recaptcha module to be imported after some time delay. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the newest esnext it's now possible to do it using top level await.
(https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)

to enable top level await for Angular:

1. use esnext (es2022) in module and es2017 or higher in target (tsconfig.json)

```
"target": "es2017", // or higher
"module": "esnext",
```

2. enable experiments.topLevelAwait for webpack (webpack.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
    experiments: { topLevelAwait: true }
};
```

3. you can now use await outside async functions

```
const fix = await import('library').then(
  _ => loaded = true
)
```